# How to multiply values of two edittext on textchangelistner and show result in anthor edittext and vise versa in android

Tags: android

I multiplied the values in two edittext et_weight and et_rate and got result in the other edittext.Now i want to divide et_freight and et_weight to get result in et_rate when i change value in et_freight.Can anyone suggest a method

```
      et_weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (!et_rate.getText().toString().equals("") && !et_weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        et_freight.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(et_weight.getText().toString()) * Integer.valueOf(et_rate.getText().toString())));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
            et_rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (!et_rate.getText().toString().equals("") && !et_weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        et_freight.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(et_weight.getText().toString()) * Integer.valueOf(et_rate.getText().toString())));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

    et_freight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!et_freight.getText().toString().equals("") && !et_weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                et_rate.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(et_freight.getText().toString()) / Integer.valueOf(et_weight.getText().toString())));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: check if this helps or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566012/textwatcher-ontextchanged-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-auto-complete-suggest/34566327#34566327

Comment: Sorry ... i did'nt get it

Comment: What is the problem with current code. ?

Comment: when i change the value in et_freight edittext .. app stops...because i already et_rate textchangelistner so when i change it the et_rate.addTextchangeListner condition starts working... This makes error

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop. Can you update description

Comment: Yes,this is infinite loop... I want a solution for this... Can we check condition vise versa in textchangelistener

Comment: Can anyone suggest alternative method for this

Comment: Is this method possible?

Comment: I will try to write a solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by checking if the `EditText` is focused before changing it's value. For example the first condition:

```
if (et_weight.isFocused() && !et_rate.getText().toString().equals("") && !et_weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
```

Also, to simplify your code you can create some *helper* methods like these:

```
private void updateDivide(){
    int weight = Integer.valueOf(et_weight.getText().toString());
    int freight = Integer.valueOf(et_freight.getText().toString());
    et_rate.setText(String.valueOf(freight / weight));
}

private void updateMultiply(){
    int weight = Integer.valueOf(et_weight.getText().toString());
    int rate = Integer.valueOf(et_rate.getText().toString());
    et_freight.setText(String.valueOf(weight * rate));
}

private boolean isSet(EditText editText){
    return !editText.getText().toString().matches("");
}
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
et_weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){

        if (et_weight.isFocused() && isSet(et_weight) && isSet(et_rate)) {
            updateMultiply();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

    }
});

et_rate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){

        if (et_rate.isFocused() && isSet(et_rate) && isSet(et_weight)) {
            updateMultiply();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

    }
});

et_freight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count){

        if (et_freight.isFocused() && isSet(et_weight) && isSet(et_freight)) {
            updateDivide();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s){

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas Roulin.... This code woks perfectly...Thnz alotzzz.. :)